# How to move an object using arrow keys using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to be able to move a rectangle (that I created using javascript) around using the arrow keys. Also I want it to stop when hitting the end of my canvas. How do I do that? I'm all new at this and have absolutely no clue.

```js
function fillRect () {

var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas"); 
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var rectX=10;
var rectY=10;

context.rect(rectX,rectY,50,50);         
context.fillStyle = "#666666";
context.fill();
}

  function onkeydown(e) {
  if(e.keyCode==39) {rectX++;} //right arrow
  elseif(e.keyCode==37) {rectX--;} //left arrow
  elseif(e.keyCode==38) {rectY--;} //up arrow
  elseif(e.keyCode==40) {rectY++;} //down arrow
  fillRect();
}
window.addEventListener("keydown", onkeydown);
```

```css
#myCanvas {
margin: auto;
display: block;
width: 80%;
height: 400px;
background-color: white;
border: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!-- Jessica Odefjord -->
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
 <html lang="sv">
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="inlämningsuppgift_javascript_jessicaodefjord.css" />
   <script type="text/javascript" src="inlämningsuppgift_javascript_jessicaodefjord.js"></script>
   <title>Flytta rektangeln</title>
  </head>
   <body>
    <header>
     <h1>Flytta rektangeln</h1>
     <h2>Flytta runt rektangeln med hjälp av piltangenterna</h2>
    </header>
     <main>
      <section id="firstsection">
       <h3>
       </h3>
      </section>
       <canvas id="myCanvas">
       </canvas>
     </main>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going through with the code gdros and yourself provided:

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/k3akqz3c/1/

```
// Basic variables
var canvas;
var context;
var rectX = 10;
var rectY = 10;

// Set canvas context
window.onload = function() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");
}

function fillRect() {
    context.beginPath();
    context.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, 1000 + canvas.width, 1000 + canvas.height);
    context.beginPath();
    context.fillStyle = "#666666";

    // Check if the rect isn't out of bounds, if so: place it back.
    if (rectX < 0) {
        rectX = 0;
    } else if (rectX > 250) {
        rectX = 250;
    }
    if (rectY < 0) {
        rectY = 0;
    } else if (rectX > 100) {
        rectX = 100;
    }

    context.fillRect(rectX, rectY, 50, 50);
}

function onkeydown(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 39) {
        rectX++;
    } //right arrow
    else if (e.keyCode == 37) {
        rectX--;
    } //left arrow
    else if (e.keyCode == 38) {
        rectY--;
    } //up arrow
    else if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        rectY++;
    } //down arrow
    fillRect();
}
window.addEventListener("keydown", onkeydown);
```

Essentially, you're recreating the rectangle every time you press one of the arrow keys, on a different position.

Answer (score 0):

First of all declare to variables that will hold the position of your rectangle. For example:

```
var rectX=0;
var rectY=0;
```

Then at `context.rect(0,0,50,50);` replace the `0,0` with the above variables like this:

```
context.rect(rectX,rectY,50,50);
```

Finally add a key handler on your window:

```
function onkeydown(e) {
  if(e.keyCode==39) {rectX++;} //right arrow
  else if(e.keyCode==37) {rectX--;} //left arrow
  else if(e.keyCode==38) {rectY--;} //up arrow
  else if(e.keyCode==40) {rectY++;} //down arrow
  fillRect();
}
window.addEventListener("keydown", onkeydown);
```

Comment: Thanks for you help, but it's not working :/ My rectangle is not showing.

Comment: But do you know how I can make the rectangle stop when hitting the end of the canvas?

Comment: Well, after calculating the new values for `rectX` and `rectY` you could add some if statements to check those values. For example `if(rectX<0) {rectX=0;}`, `if(rectY<0) {rectY=0;}`, ...